# How can I correctly display fetched JSON data in to DOM with Async/await

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I try to display fetched JSON data in to DOM with Async/await but I can't display this specific data
**{name: first,last}**.I'm Junior Developer and open to all good learning advice for this topic :)

**JavaScript**

```
async function getJson(){
    const response = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10');
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log(data);
    document.getElementById('authors').textContent =JSON.stringify(data.results[0]);
}
getJson();
```

**HTML**

```
<p id="authors"></p>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your Javascript snippet should like in this below code snippet.

```js
async function getJson(){
    const response = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10');
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log(data);
    document.getElementById('authors').textContent =JSON.stringify(data.results[0].name.first + " " + data.results[0].name.last);
}
getJson();
```

```html
<div id="authors"></div>
```

After the results[0] it is very vague for the code to understand what to print that's why you are seeing the entire json data.

Instead you specify the particular key in from the json. In this the name key to the get the corresponding value.

```
document.getElementById('authors').textContent =JSON.stringify(data.results[0].name.first + " " + data.results[0].name.last);
```

Comment: Thanks Gautham is there any great way to display all first and last names in this data.

Comment: You can iterate the json response in a for loop with the data.results as the length of the for loop, to display all the names.